# Pre populate SQLite Database in iONIC Cordova iOS

Tags: ios, sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework

I created the initial slide menu application using ionic.

I've a db file in my project, How can i access this.

I want to access the existing data base in my project and populate the data in my app.

I tried below plugins and other tutorials but I can't able to access the data base file.

> https://github.com/litehelpers/cordova-sqlite-ext

Anyone can you please help and suggest me something in this. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To prepopulate your database you can do this :

Run these commands:

```
git clone https://github.com/nolanlawson/cordova-prepopulated-database-demo.git
cd cordova-prepopulated-database-demo
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-sqlite-2
```

Then to run on iOS:

```
cordova platform add ios
cordova run ios
```

Or to run on Android:

```
cordova platform add android
cordova run android
```

You have now a file called `mydatabase.db` in www/. This is a simple database, with the following structure:

```
>.schema
CREATE TABLE mytable (foo text, bar text);
>SELECT * FROM mytable;
hello|world
```

You just have to edit this file to populate the database as you wish !

More information on this github : https://github.com/nolanlawson/cordova-prepopulated-database-demo

Hope it will help you ;)

Comment: I ll try it now and come up with you @dylan

Comment: @Dylan I received the table data as Firstname, Lastname, Mobile, Company like using below code `if(res.rows.length > 0) {
                                                                                                  for(var i = 0; i < res.rows.length; i++) {
                                                                                                  }` But How can i get this all table records to dictionary and how can i access from anywhere in my application is that any way like this ?

Comment: Mmmmh sorry I'm still quite a noob myself so I don't really know. I searched for it, if I find something I'll notice you !